# Since yesterday, I can not access mercadolibre.com.ar anymore

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help, ssl, https, nyx

Thanks for such a good program. 
Since yesterday, mercadolibre.com.ar does not work for me anymore. It lets me navigate and view the products but it won't let me login to my account:

https://www.mercadolibre.com/jms/mla/lgz/login?go=http://www.mercadolibre.com.ar/gz/home/logged?display=page

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your question. This Q&A page relies on a english-speaking audience. So it would be good if you could ask in english.

Comment: Look closely at that URL. The login page is not hosted on ...com.ar but on ...com which appears to block connections from exit nodes.